# Can Anybody Explain Why This Script Cannot Be Uploaded as an External Resource?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I am currently working within Tumblr's theme builder framework, and have been facing some difficulties uploading certain scripts as external resources. Upon several upload attempts, I continuously received an error message implying that Tumblr does not accept .html files to be uploaded as an asset, even though the file I am attempting to upload is a .js file.

I suppose it's worth noting that my site runs via HTTPS, so why would a code, (as shown below), not be able to be loaded as an external source/asset?

UPDATE: Ok, so far the issue has something to do with this portion of HTML in the script:

```
if (photos[j].alt_sizes[1]) {
        imgURL = photos[j].alt_sizes[1].url;
        // console.log(imgURL, linkURL);
      } else {
        continue;
      }
      $("#tumblr-posts").append(
        "<li><a href=" +
          linkURL +
          "><img src=" +
          imgURL +
          " /></a>" +
          "</li>"
      );
    }
```

The denied external JS (mycustomscript.js):

```
apiKey = "API-HIDDEN";
limit = 4;
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/MYTUMBLRID.tumblr.com/posts?limit=4",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  data: {
    api_key: apiKey,
    tag: "blog"
  },
  success: function(results) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < results.response.posts.length) {
      var type = results.response.posts[i].type;
      if (type == "photo") {
        var photos = results.response.posts[i].photos;
        var linkURL = results.response.posts[i].post_url;
        var caption = results.response.posts[i].caption;
        for (var j = 0; j < photos.length; j++) {
          if (photos[j].alt_sizes[1]) {
            imgURL = photos[j].alt_sizes[1].url;
            // console.log(imgURL, linkURL);
          } else {
            continue;
          }
          $("#tumblr-posts").append(
            "<li><a href=" +
              linkURL +
              "><img src=" +
              imgURL +
              " /></a>" +
              "</li>"
          );
        }
      }
      i++;
    }
    console.log(results.response);
  }
});
```

How I've attempted to call for the script, (x's in place to conceal hidden link portions):

```
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/x/x/mycustomscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: As a debugging attempt, remove all html from said file (the append)

Comment: try replaceing `http://` with `//`. AFAIK, you cannot load scripts from insecure locations within a secure site.

Comment: @KevinB, Thanks. This proved that there is definitely an issue with the HTML in the script...

Answer (score 0):

It’s due the HTML tags in the script. You can work around this by splitting the HTML tags so

```
"<li>"
```

Becomes

```
"<"+"li>"
```

And do the same with end tags too.